# Difficulty screen scraping http://www.momondo.com using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have some difficulty to extract the total price (css selector = '.total') from the flight result.

```
http://www.momondo.com/multicity/?Search=true&TripType=oneway&SegNo=1&SO0=KUL&SD0=KBR&SDP0=31-12-2012&AD=2&CA=0,0&DO=false&NA=false#Search=true&TripType=oneway&SegNo=1&SO0=KUL&SD0=KBR&SDP0=31-12-2012&AD=2&CA=0,0&DO=false&NA=false
```

I get the error "undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass nokogiri ".

My code

```
desc "Fetch product prices"
task :fetch_details => :environment do
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'open-uri'
  include ERB::Util

  OneWayFlight.find_all_by_money(nil).each do |flight|
    url = "http://www.momondo.com/multicity/Search=true&TripType=oneway&SegNo=1&SO0=KUL&SD0=KBR&SDP0=31-12-2012&AD=2&CA=0,0&DO=false&NA=false#Search=true&TripType=oneway&SegNo=1&SO0=KUL&SD0=KBR&SDP0=31-12-2012&AD=2&CA=0,0&DO=false&NA=false"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    price = doc.at_css(".total").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
    flight.update_attribute(:price, price)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The content you're attempting to scrape appears to be populated by JS after the page loads. To see for yourself, inspect the content of `div#flight_results` of the document you're currently parsing:

```
url = 'http://www.momondo.com/multicity/?Search=true&TripType=oneway&SegNo=1&SO0=KUL&SD0=KBR&SDP0=31-12-2012&AD=2&CA=0,0&DO=false&NA=false#Search=true&TripType=oneway&SegNo=1&SO0=KUL&SD0=KBR&SDP0=31-12-2012&AD=2&CA=0,0&DO=false&NA=false'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.at_css('div#flight_results').to_html #=> '<div id="flight_results"></div>'
```

Though it is outside of the scope of this question, you can generally reconstruct the JS requests used to populate the content you're after.